# C#8.0 Herencia múltiple en implementación de interfaces con métodos predeterminados

Tags: c#, herencia, interface, c#-8.0

> Pregunta basada en *[Do C# 8 default interface implementations allow for multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278587/do-c-sharp-8-default-interface-implementations-allow-for-multiple-inheritance)*

---

Una de las nuevas características de [c#-8.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-8.0)  [permite realizar la implementación de métodos desde una interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-members).

Por ejemplo:

```
public interface A { int Foo() => 1; }
public interface B { int Foo() => 2; }
public class C : A, B { }
```

Lo que genera la siguiente pregunta,

¿Qué se producirá si creamos una instancia de `C` e intentamos llamar a `Foo()`?

```
C c = new C();
c.Foo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Traducción de la [respuesta de *user247702*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53297433/5213794)

---

Según [Mads Torgersen en su blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/building-c-8-0/)

> Las interfaces, aún están muy lejos de las clases abstractas, Las
>   clases no heredan miembros de las interfaces, porr lo que si una
>   interfaz define un miembro M, esto no implica que la clase que hereda
>   tenga a M, Es algo como una implementación explícita, para accerder al
>   método de la interfaz, será necesario llamarlo usando el tipo de la
>   interfaz.

Por lo cual, siguiendo el ejemplo de la pregunta:

```
public interface A { int Foo() => 1; }
public interface B { int Foo() => 2; }
public class C : A, B { }
```

No puede hacerse esto:

```
var ejemplo = new C();
var x = ejemplo.Foo(); /* no compilará */
```

Sin embargo, lo siguiente si es posible

```
var ejemplo = new C();
var x = ((A)ejemplo).Foo(); /* llama a la implementación provista por A */
var y = ((B)ejemplo).Foo(); /* llama a la implementación provista por B */
```